# How to collect values every n seconds with a max count in each interval from a signal in ReactiveSwift?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-swift

It seems like a combination of `collect(every:on:skipEmpty:discardWhenCompleted:)` and `collect(count:)` in ReactiveSwift.
The resulting signal would send an event every **n** seconds if the count of accumulated values doesn't reach max count during each time interval. But if in a specific time interval, the count of values has reached max count, it will send immediately.

For example, timeInterval = 2s, maxCount = 2
[image]

- interval 1: received two values [1, 2], forward them at end of interval 1
- interval 2: received one value [3], forward them at end of interval 2
- interval 3: received three values [5, 6, **7**] ( 3 values > maxCount), forward [5, 6] immediately when 7 is received and 7 is regarded as received value in interval 4 (interval 3 stopped early)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension SignalProducer {
    func collect(count: Int, every: DispatchTimeInterval, on scheduler: QueueScheduler) -> SignalProducer<[Value], Error> {
        SignalProducer<[Value], Error> { (observer: Signal<[Value], Error>.Observer, lifetime: Lifetime) in
            var collectedValues: [Value] = []
            
            let disposable = CompositeDisposable()
            
            disposable += self
                .observe(on: scheduler)
                .start(Signal<Value, Error>.Observer(value: { value in
                    collectedValues.append(value)
                    
                    if collectedValues.count == count {
                        observer.send(value: collectedValues)
                        collectedValues.removeAll()
                    }
                },
                                                     failed: { error in
                    observer.send(error: error)
                },
                                                     completed: {
                    if collectedValues.count > 0 {
                        observer.send(value: collectedValues)
                        collectedValues.removeAll()
                    }
                    
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                },
                                                     interrupted: {
                    observer.sendInterrupted()
                }))
            
            disposable += SignalProducer<Date, Never>.timer(interval: every,
                                                            on: scheduler)
            .observe(on: scheduler)
            .startWithValues { _ in
                observer.send(value: collectedValues)
                collectedValues.removeAll()
            }
            
            lifetime.observeEnded {
                disposable.dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It collects an array of values until it reaches a certain count and then fires or fires every time interval.

Test:

```
var counter = 0
let valuesGenerator = SignalProducer.timer(interval: .milliseconds(550), on: QueueScheduler.main)
    .filter { date in
        Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date) % 3 == 0
    }
    .map { _ in
        defer { counter += 1 }
        return counter
    }
    .take(first: 20)
    .promoteError(Error.self)
        
valuesGenerator
.collect(count: 3, every: .seconds(5), on: QueueScheduler.main)
.start(Signal<[Int], Error>.Observer(value: { values in
       print("valuesGenerator, date: \(Date()), values: \(values)")
    },
                                         failed: { error in
        print("valuesGenerator, date: \(Date()), error: \(error)")
    },
                                         completed: {
        print("valuesGenerator, date: \(Date()), completed")
    },
                                         interrupted: {
        print("valuesGenerator, date: \(Date()), interrupted")
    }))
```

Output:

```
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:37:51 +0000, values: [0, 1, 2]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:37:51 +0000, values: [3]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:37:56 +0000, values: [4, 5]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:00 +0000, values: [6, 7, 8]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:01 +0000, values: [9]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:06 +0000, values: [10, 11, 12]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:06 +0000, values: []
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:11 +0000, values: [13, 14]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:15 +0000, values: [15, 16, 17]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:16 +0000, values: []
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:21 +0000, values: [18, 19]
valuesGenerator, date: 2024-02-16 16:38:21 +0000, completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is hard to grasp, but I will try.

If you want to batch emitted values by count and time, you can use bufferTimeout method. See documentation here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-

Some example:

```
void bufferTimeoutTry() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(157))
            .filter(time -> time > 20 && time < 38 || time % 5 == 0 || time % 17 == 0)
            .bufferTimeout(5, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .doOnNext(list -> {
                // we will get list of items buffered in 1-second period of time, or at most 5 items.
            })
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

Output will be list of items. `Flux.interval` is generating sequential long number (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...), it is filtered on second line of method (to get some non interval behavior) and than buffer-ed. After buffer, there is no long on stream, but it has changed to list of longs.

```
[0, 5]
[10, 15]
[17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
[34, 35, 36, 37, 40]
[45, 50, 51]
[55, 60]
[65, 68, 70]
[75, 80]
[85, 90]
[95, 100]
[102, 105]
[110, 115]
[119, 120, 125]
[130, 135, 136]
[140, 145]
[150, 153, 155]
[160, 165]
[170, 175]
[180, 185]
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: You can try to use `.bufferTimeout(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).flatMap(f -> f)`. Second approach can be `windowTimeout(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2))` and than just again  `.flatMap(f -> f)`. This will behave a bit differently (it will pass things as soon as possible).

Comment: Cool! It's exactly what I'm looking for. But I failed to find something similar to this operator in ReactiveSwift. It seems that I should implement this by myself.